# Perl: hash from import JSON data, Dumper Outputs right data, However I can not access it

Tags: json, perl, hash

I have the following data in .json;  actual values substituted.

```
{ "Mercury": [
        {
        "Long": "0.xxxxxx",
        "LongP": "0.xxxxx",
        "Eccent": "0.xxxx",
        "Semi": "0.xxxx",
        "Inclin": "0.xxxx",
        "ascnode": "0.xx.xxxx",
        "adia": "0.xxx",
        "visual": "-0.xx"
        }
]
}
```

This works fine:

```
my %data = ();

my $json        = JSON->new();
my $data        = $json->decode($json_text);

my $planet      = "Mercury";

print Dumper $data;    # prints:
```

This is all fine:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Mercury' => [
                         {
                           'Inclin' => '7.',
                           'Semi' => '0.8',
                           'adia' => '6.7',
                           'LongP' => '77.29',
                           'visual' => '-0.00',
                           'Long' => '60.000',
                           'Eccent' => '0.0000',
                           'ascnode' => '48.0000'
                         }
                       ]
        };
```

However when I try to access the hash:

```
my $var = $data{$planet}{Long};
```

I get empty values, why?

Comment: `$data` is a reference and the planet key contains an arrayref, so try `$data->{$planet}[0]{Long}` instead, see [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref) for more information

Comment: Thank you!! That solved the problem in whole. @Håkon

Comment: `%data` and `$data` are two different variables: the fist one is a hash, while the second one is a scalar. Your first `my %data = ()` serves no purpose given the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

`$data{$planet}` accesses hash `%data`, but you populated scalar `$data`.

You want `$data->{$planet}` instead of `$data{$planet}`.

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have caught this error.

---

**Problem 2**

`$data->{$planet}` returns a reference to an array.

You want `$data->{$planet}[0]{Long}` (first element) or `$data->{$planet}[-1]{Long}` (last element) instead of `$data->{$planet}{Long}`. Maybe. An array suggests the number of elements isn't always going to be one, so you might want a loop.

Comment: _Always use use strict; use warnings;. It would have caught this error._ In that specific case it wouldn't have because OP declared `my %data` in his code. (not that this is a bad advice; of course OP should always use strict and warnings, but for once, this was not the issue)

Comment: @Dada, I bet they were using `use strict;`, it did catch the problem, but they declared `%data` rather than start using the var they already declared and assigned to. Or maybe not. *shrug*

Comment: This explanation actually makes a lot of sense! Great knowledge of Perl and its beginners you have :D